# Foreach loop to see result in Rich text box but only seeing first query result.?

Tags: c#, oracle, foreach

I have table names in my list box to check if same tables has same columns. For Example

listBox3 has EMPLOYEE table name my query has to check if EMPLOYEE table has different columns.

This query working like for example: userA has Employee table and UserB has Employee table too. After comparing the Employee table from both user I am getting the Alter statements on richTextBox1.

Depends on my EMPLOYEE table I suppose to see the result like below;

alter table EMPLOYEE add DESCRIPTION VARCHAR2 (15) ;

alter table EMPLOYEE add CITY   VARCHAR2 (10) ;

but Only seeing:

alter table EMPLOYEE add DESCRIPTION VARCHAR2 (15) ;

```
 foreach (string Items in listBox3.Items)
                    {
                        using (OracleCommand crtCommand = new OracleCommand("with src as(select src.table_name src_table_name, src.column_name src_col_name, src.data_type src_data_type, src.data_length src_data_len, src.data_precision src_data_precision, src.data_scale src_data_scale, src.nullable src_nullable,decode(T.Constraint_Type,'P', 'Primary Key','U','Unique','') as src_cons from  all_tab_columns src left join (select Cc.Column_Name,Uc.Constraint_Type from user_cons_columns cc, user_constraints uc where Cc.Constraint_Name = Uc.Constraint_Name and Cc.Table_Name = Uc.Table_Name) t on T.Column_Name = Src.Column_Name where table_name = '" + Items + "' and owner='" + txtSrcUserID.Text + "'), tgt as(select tgt.table_name tgt_table_name, tgt.column_name tgt_col_name, tgt.data_type tgt_data_type, tgt.data_length tgt_data_len, tgt.data_precision tgt_data_precision, tgt.data_scale tgt_data_scale, tgt.nullable tgt_nullable, decode(T.Constraint_Type,'P', 'Primary Key','U','Unique','') as tgt_cons from all_tab_columns tgt left join (select Cc.Column_Name,Uc.Constraint_Type from user_cons_columns cc, user_constraints uc where Cc.Constraint_Name = Uc.Constraint_Name and Cc.Table_Name = Uc.Table_Name) t on T.Column_Name = tgt.Column_Name where table_name = '"+Items+"' and owner='" + txtDesUserID.Text + "'), col_details as(select src.src_table_name, nvl(tgt.tgt_table_name, first_value(tgt_table_name) over(order by tgt_table_name nulls last)) tgt_table_name, src.src_col_name, src.src_data_type, src.src_data_len, src.src_data_precision, src.src_data_scale, src.src_nullable,src_cons, tgt.tgt_col_name, tgt.tgt_data_type, tgt.tgt_data_len, tgt.tgt_data_precision, tgt.tgt_data_scale, tgt.tgt_nullable,tgt_cons from src full outer join tgt on (src.src_col_name = tgt.tgt_col_name))select * from (select case when tgt_data_type != src_data_type or tgt_data_len != src_data_len or tgt_data_precision != src_data_precision or tgt_data_scale != src_data_scale or tgt_nullable != src_nullable then 'alter table ' || tgt_table_name || ' modify ' || tgt_col_name || ' ' || src_data_type || ' ' || case when src_data_type in ('DATE') then null else case when src_data_type in ('VARCHAR', 'VARCHAR2') then ' (' ||nvl(to_char(src_data_len), ' ') || ') 'else  decode(nvl(src_data_precision, -1), -1, null, nvl(to_char(src_data_precision), ' ') || ', ' || nvl(to_char(src_data_scale), ' ') || ')') end end || case when tgt_nullable = 'Y' then ' null ' else ' not null ' end || tgt_cons when tgt_col_name is null then 'alter table ' || tgt_table_name || ' add ' || src_col_name || ' ' ||  ' ' || ' ' || src_data_type || ' ' || case when src_data_type in ('DATE') then null else case when src_data_type in ('VARCHAR', 'VARCHAR2')then '('|| nvl(to_char(src_data_len), ' ') || ') ' else  decode(nvl(src_data_precision, -1), -1, null, nvl(to_char(src_data_precision), ' ') || ', ' || nvl(to_char(src_data_scale), ' ') || ')')end end || tgt_cons when src_col_name is null then 'alter table '|| tgt_table_name ||' drop '||tgt_col_name end alter_statement from col_details) where alter_statement is not null", conn1))
                        {
                            var result = crtCommand.ExecuteScalar();

                            if (result != null)
                            {
                                richTextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
                                richTextBox1.AppendText(result.ToString() + ";");
                                richTextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                continue;
                            }

                        }   
                 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `OracleDataReader` like below  to display results if you have more records returning from the query, and also never use inline parameters in your sql, better to use parameterized query to avoid sql injection attacks.

```
using (OracleCommand crtCommand = new OracleCommand(sql, Con))
using (OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {

        if(!reader.IsDBNull(0)) 
               richTextBox1.AppendLine(reader[0].ToString(); + ";");

    }
}
```

Comment: is there is a null value in result can I also continue to check next table in the list box with this query/

Comment: You can check null like `reader.IsDBNull(0)` if this return true then you have null value